# for_form increment issue increment object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am probably overlooking something but this has me stumped....I have a form which will display a survey (it actually is rendered in a a partial) and I am using :remote => true to pass to the controller (update) thru and ajax call via jQuery, when I render back to the  the view via a js.erb I replace the question with the next question and the id with the next id to render in the original form (in hidden fields) but thats not doing the job the first display after submit renders the next question text but the id is not incrementing and the next submit call is actually submitting to the first record. Is there a js command that will increment this in the erb.

My code is shown here below

```
<%= form_for(@category, :remote => true)  do |f| %>
<ul id='questionarea'>
<%=@current_question %>
</ul>
<div id = 'hidden_field_usr' >
<%=f.hidden_field :user_id, {:value => params[:id]}  %>
</div>
<div id = 'hidden_field_question' >
<%=f.hidden_field :question_id, {:value => @current_question_id} %>
</div>
 <%=f.fields_for @answer do |a| %>

    <ul id= 'answerarea'>
    <%= a.radio_button(:agree , 5) %>
    <%= a.label(:agree_5, "I completely agree ") %>
    <%= a.radio_button(:agree , 4) %>
    <%= a.label(:agree_4, "I agree ") %>
    <%= a.radio_button(:agree , 3) %>
    <%= a.label(:agree_3, "I kind of agree ") %>
    <%= a.radio_button(:agree , 2) %>
    <%= a.label(:agree_2, "I disagree ") %>
    <%= a.radio_button(:agree , 1) %>
    <%= a.label(:agree_1, "I completly disagree ") %>

      This statement is:

    <%= a.radio_button(:importance , 3) %>
    <%= a.label(:importance_3, "Incredibly important ") %>
    <%= a.radio_button(:importance , 2) %>
    <%= a.label(:importance_2, "Kind of important") %>
    <%= a.radio_button(:importance , 3) %>
    <%= a.label(:importance_1, "A good thing trade for")%>
</ul>
<ul>
        <li id ='comments'>Comments:
         <%= a.text_field :comments %>
       </li>
 </ul>
  <ul>
<%end %>
<div id = "qsubmit" > <%= f.submit %> </div>
  <%end %>
```

My Controller looks like .....

```
 def update
 @formresults = params[:category]     
 @category = Category.find(params[:id])    
 @formresults = params[:category]     
 @question_id = @formresults[:question_id]
 @user_id = @formresults[:user_id]
 @answer_details = @formresults[:answer]

 @answer=@category.questions.find(@question_id).answers.find_by_user_id(@user_id)
 @answer.agree = @answer_details[:agree]
 @answer.importance = @answer_details[:importance]
 @answer.importance = @answer_details[:comments]

 if @answer.save then
         @counter = @question_id.to_i
         @counter = @counter+1
         @current_question_rec = @category.questions.find(@counter)
         @current_question = @current_question_rec.question 
         @current_question_id = @counter
         @answer = @category.questions.find(@current_question_id).answers.find_by_user_id(@user_id)


 respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to @category }
         format.js { render }
 end 
end
end
```

update.js.erb....

```
$('#questionarea').html( "<%= escape_javascript render :partial =>  "current_question" %> ");
$('#hiddenparms').html( "<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "hiddenparms" %> ");
```

Not sure if this has something to do with it but I have a nested resource which has only one record and this is were my form_for origintes is it possible to increment from the question level in a fields_for or should I just eliminate the top level altogether and just start my forms_for at the question level then create a new method in the categories controller to handle this gonna try that and if it works will post as a my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to mark this as answered as I suspected the form_for loop would only generate 1 record as I was using the category object as my loop were I should have used the question object Thanks Rubybrah for your information this seems to be a couldn't see the forest for the tree issues on my part

Answer (score 0):

do you have your app/code on github? If you share the link, then I might look into that matter.

I think I found the mistake, can you please show your MODELS.

```
if @answer.save then
     @counter = @question_id.to_i
     @counter = @counter+1
!here=> @current_question_rec = @category.questions.find(@counter)
     @current_question = @current_question_rec.question 
     @current_question_id = @counter
     @answer = @category.questions.find(@current_question_id).answers.find_by_user_id(@user_id)


   respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to @category }
       format.js { render }
   end 
end
```

I JUST UPDATED THIS - THE ERROR IS:
=> You want to skip to the next question, BUT you are not passing in the right parameters. Now, that I have seen your question.rb (model)

Try:

```
!here=> @current_question_rec = @category.questions.find_by_question_id(@counter)
```

It would be VERY USEFUL if you host your code on github (for free) and publish the link here, I might try your application myself and find out the answers.

Comment: My Category class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :pic ,:small_pic, :question_attributes
 has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :name,  :id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

Comment: Ok, now please write your Questions.rb (model)

Comment: my question.rb

        class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :category_id, :question, :question_id, :answers_attributes
        belongs_to :categories
        has_many :answers
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
        end

Comment: and finally my answers

        class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :question
 belongs_to :user
end

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb6b7aa8c>):
  app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:75:in `update

Comment: I created a repo in git its under janbenson/demo btw still not working after I changed the line find_by_question_id

Comment: i look into it right now, if i can solve the problem i will post it.

Comment: None of your "tables" work. When and how did you migrate that application? There is a lot missing, right?

Comment: just copied it over from another site locally I guess I could recreate the migrations if necessary I did change some objects but that was outside the app theres a sqlite.development file in config

Comment: I am sorry, I cant help you unless the app works correct in that way, that i can migrate the database. I have no way of knowing what is going on. if you're interested, skype me: 'rubybrah' I have not enough points to chat with you here, I will post the answer here, if we find it.

Comment: yup I just sent you a invite on skype

Comment: btw I am janinpleasanton on sykpe